# Aviary web SDK crop tool and mobile browser features not working

Tags: mobile, web, adobecreativesdk

I am developing a web site which uses the aviary SDK web. What I has found is the crop feature cannot use to rectangular crop of image.
For mobile applications I cannot use meme feature. Keyboard is not displaying and other features also not properly use.
you can see the tool added at http://dev.canvastory.com/get-started/idea-1.html.
select dimension from dropdown and click next. Then next tab appears and you can upload photo using facebook, instagram , computer or dropbox. 
Please check and give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [Creative SDK Image Editor guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/web/#/articles/imageeditorui/index.html), the Image Editor isn't currently optimized for mobile devices:

> For handheld use we generally recommend our native SDKs (iOS, and Android), which have a UI optimized for smaller screens and performance tuned to the native device.

In some cases, when using the Web SDK on a mobile device, certain tools may not work as expected and the layout may not fit the screen.